# How to prevent keyboard open on Ionic 4? (Android)

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard

I'm trying prevent the open keyboard action when the input is focused.
My app will run on Handheld (A demostration: https://www.mclogistica.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Dolphin99gx.jpg) so I don't need an open keyboard.
I want to prevent an open or disable event.

I have used this code but unfortunately it didn't work:

```
this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

The log doesn't appear.

Comment: which plugin do you use to detect keyboard events?

Comment: i'm using this plugin: `@ionic-native/keyboard/ngx`. [Here is the doc](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard)